# Anonymous classes, accessing private properties of extended class

Tags: php

Fully aware that things like Mockery exist, I'm trying to see what testing in PHPUnit would be like using straight PHP. This is only possible with the advent of anonymous classes. What I have works perfectly, unless the property I want to override in my extended class is private, then it of course fails. Here's a small example of how a test might look like:

```
$test = new class() extends ClassImExtending {
        // user is protected in ClassImExtending, and its value is 
        // injected User
        public $user;

        public function __construct() {
            // Overwrites ClassImExtending constructor so that I don't 
            // have to inject all the same dependencies for the purpose 
            // of my test

            // By extending User, it forces any methods I'm overriding 
            // to accept the same number and type of arguments
            $this->user = new class() extends User {
                public function getUser() {
                    $user = new User;
                    $user->id = 1;
                    return $user;
                }
            };
        }
}
```

So essentially, as long as the property $user in ClassImExtending is protected or public, and the method I'm testing doesn't use any other ClassImExtending properties besides $user, then the following will work great:

```
$result = $test->methodImTestingInClassImExtending();
```

But like I said previously, if $user is private, methodImTestingInClassImExtending() of course won't even look at my anonymous class override property $user at all, it'll look at $user within ClassImExtending, which of course the value of is null since my anonymous class overrides the class constructor where $user is given a value in ClassImExtending.

I've been trying to play around with Closures or anything similar to try and see if I could make this setup somehow have access to the private property of the class I'm extending so that I can override the value. I recognize that this defeats the purpose of private properties and isn't a typical use case. But for the purposes of testing what I'm doing within the concept of unit testing... does anyone have any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: The [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) is what you're looking for. Check out the dupe for an example of how to do what you're talking about

Comment: @machavity, I feel like my question has more to it than the duplicate you're pointing to. I can't figure out how to use reflection classes for my specific purpose. Using the code example given, could you help point in the right direction for how I can have the anonymous class extend ClassImExtending, and yet have it point to a reflection's now accessible property?